# What are these numbers for this element name?

Tags: instructions, size

I have a part inventory for a set and it has some axles with numbers next to them. This is not a technic set, but I imagine the numbers are the same as in this question - [LEGO Technic part Numbers](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4747/lego-technic-part-numbers)

But one of the axles has two numbers (5,5) - is this a comma because of the locale in which it was purchased uses the comma as the USA would use a (dot) for a decimal? Or does it have something to do with the fact that the collar on the axle isn't at the end?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bricklink lists it as

> Technic, Axle 5.5 with stop

The blue number is the length of the axle. It is mentioned in the part list to distinguish axles of different lengths in a set.

In this case, the length is 5.5, so yes, it is written as `5,5` because of the locale.